# What is the purpose of this mov before call in x86 asm?

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I'm just learning ASM/x86, so please bear with me.

## Question

I noticed the following in the program I'm inspecting, and I'm thinking that it is passing a parameter to the function that gets called:

```
mov   [ebp-04],00000005
call  <some function call here>
```

As far as I can tell, this seems to be setting the second byte from the top of the stack to the value `5`.

Is this effectively passing a parameter of 5 to the function?

Would it resemble the following in `C`:

```
void someFunction(int num); //function declaration

someFunction(5); //In some context
```

If it is passing a single parameter of 5 to the function, why is it set as the second byte (-04), and not the top of the stack? What is at the top of the stack? Am I interpreting this all wrong?

**EDIT**
The top of the function is where `ebp` gets set:

```
push  ebp
mov   ebp,esp
push  -01
push  184
mov   eax,fs:[00000000]
...   //bunch more pushes and movs with eax and ecx into [ebp-offset]
...   //a couple of jump if equals
...   //some more push and movs
lea   ecx,[ebp-1C]
mov   [ebp-04],00000005
call  <some function>
```

Here is the called function:

```
 mov   edx,[ecx]
 mov   eax,[ecx+08]
 sub   eax,edx
 test  edx,edx
 je    <label1>
 cmp   eax,00000080
 jna   <label2>
 push  edx
 call  <another function>
 add   esp,04
 ret
label2:
 push  eax
 push  edx
 call  <yet another function>
 add   esp,08
label1:
 ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ebp` is not the stack pointer, that's `esp`. `ebp` is customarily used as frame pointer, so depending on how it was set up it may indeed be passing that `5` as argument. Or it may just be storing it in a local variable.

Also, it might not be possible to tell whether it's a local or a function argument without knowing the function itself:

```
int x = 5;
foo();
```

may generate the same code as `foo(5);`

The frame pointer is used to point at the beginning of the stack area for the current function and has to be set up by the function itself in the prologue. Arguments are above it (positive offsets) locals are below it (negative offsets). Note that in 32 and 64 bit mode (on x86) you don't really need it because you can address relative to the stack pointer `esp` directly. Still, under some circumstances it may be useful, such as for debugging purposes.

Comment: I read on [this site](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html) that is is the "Stack Base Pointer register". What is a frame pointer? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: So, it is a local variable because it is a negative offset `[ebp-04]`?

Comment: Yes, it's among the locals. However arguments to other functions may also be in the bottom part of the locals, which is why you can't tell without studying the called function.

Comment: The top of the called function looks like: `mov  edx,[ecx]` then `mov  eax,[ecx+08]`. How does `ecx` have a value here? Is it set in the function that called this function?

Comment: If it's a c++ program on windows, it may be using `ecx` as the `this` pointer. `fs` segment is used for thread-local stuff and exceptions. The called function doesn't seem to use the `5` so I say it's not an argument.

Answer (score 2):

The example you show is not a passing a value to the function. At least it wouldn't be a typical call.

The use of the `fs` register typically is a try/catch setup.

If this is really the whole sequence of the functions (particularly the called function) then

... here it might just sets some local variable.

```
mov   [ebp-04],00000005
```

... here seems a parameterr to be passed in the ECX register

```
lea   ecx,[ebp-1C]
```

Most compiled programs use the `ebp` register as a basepointer to local variables on the stack. The individual variables are then addressed with `[ebp-X]` where X is the offset of each variable. If you have, for example, two local int variables, then you would see `[ebp-4]` and `[ebp-8]` when these two variables are addressed.

Comment: What is strange is it seems to set the local variable, then go into a function call, then set the local variable again after the function call to another static value (255). Thanks for the extra information by the way! I appreciate it. Learning all I can

Comment: You can set a memory access breakpoint and see if the value is somewhere accessed or modified. If you find the info helpfull, you are invited to upvote. ;) One thing this could mean is, to check if the exception was thrown. Install the exception, set a flag before the function call, and if the exception was not executed, the value is changed to something else. Only guessing though, it can mean something totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Generally parameters are passed by putting them in registers, or pushing them onto the stack, and then calling the targeted subroutine.

EBP often contains a pointer to a stack frame, not the stack top.  So your example seems odd at least it doesn't appear to be likely to be an argument passing operation.  It may be some other action relevant to the function in which the call is being made.

Is it compiler generated code?  If so, the compiler may know the relationship between ESP and EBP (often when entering function ESP is copied into ESP) and may be taking advantage of that knowledge.   You need to figure out where the EBP value being used is set, earlier; it would be helpful to show that code.

Comment: You want the code before the `mov` instruction, or the code at the top of the function that is being called, or both?

Comment: Working on getting that now. Had to reboot. Also, it is compiler generated code.

Comment: At the top of the function, I see: `push  ebp` and `mov ebp,esp` followed by `push -01`. There are a few other function calls and a bunch of `[ebp+someoffset]` uses following that. I guess I need to find out what is in `esp` now?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd insert the ebp-relevant instructions in you question text.  But it sounds like ebp is set to esp at function entry (just as I said), followed by one push konstant and no other effective stack changes (a call pushes a return addresss, but returning pops it off, having no net effect on ESP).  If that's the case, then ebp-4 is the first word in teh stack frame; it is overwriting the pushed "1".   What that value is, I don't know.

Comment: I'm starting to follow I think. I'm still confused on why `[ebp-4]` would be the first word in the stack frame as opposed to just `[ebp]`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Er, yes, I think you are getting it and I've mislead you a bit. Yes, [ebp] points to the first word of the stack frame, where the -1 was pushed to.  [ebp-4] points to the *second* word.  So it appears to be overwriting the 184 value with the 5 value.  Its easy to get the math and the direction wrong, and easy to be off-by-one :-{   Mostly when I work on assembly code, I have to be prepared to stare at it a long time, and do a variety of repeated mental executions to make sure I know (think?) what is going on.  Your turn :-{